# mysql doesn't ask for root password when installing

Tags: installation, php, mysql

**situation**

- I did install MySQL by using a MySQL installer and I  did fill out the content as following MySQL did ..but not asked a password ..

**try**

Anyway I tried to start mysql set-up in the command prompt..

1. `cd C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin`
2. `mysql -u root -p`
3. error (without password )

**environment**

- `windows10 64 bit`
- I installed `mysql-installer-web-community-8.0.22.0.msi`

Besides, I've ever used  `Xampp` and `Local` before for `WordPress` development ..

**I did install when setup**

・Mysql Server (latest version)

・Mysql workbranch(latest version)

・mysql Shell (latest version)

・mysql for visual studio (latest version)

**Error content**

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)
```

**my goal**

- I want to use MySQL in the visual studio with laravel ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL by default sets the username to `root` and there’s no password.
You can now run `mysql -u root -p` and be logged in without a password.
Unfortunately, some applications and services that depend on MySQL will fail if
a root password is needed for authentication.

The following method will allow you set a password, or reset it if one was defined
and forgotten.

- Run the Services applet (`services.msc`)
- Find the MySQL service, right-click that entry, then click Stop
- Create a text file containing this one line with any name,
  but here I will call it `mysql-init.txt`
  (replace "NewPassword" but keep everything else):

  ```
    ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'NewPassword';
  ```
- Run the Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`) as Administrator
- Navigate to the MySQL folder by a command similar to the following
  (version number may change):

  ```
    cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin"
  ```
- Enter the following using two slashes for each slash (`\\`):

  ```
    mysqld --init-file=C:\\path\\mysql-init.txt
  ```
- Now you may log into the MySQL server as root using the new password,
  after restarting the MySQL service.
  The file `mysql-init.txt` is no longer needed.

For more details see the article
[How to Reset or Change MySQL Root Password on Linux or Windows](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-reset-mysql-root-password-windows-linux).

Comment: Best answer which is working. For me I had to run this line `mysqld --skip-grant-tables` before running `mysqld --init-file=C:\\path\\mysql-init.txt`. And everything started working

Answer (score 0):

1. Open MySQL-Installer Community usind Windiws + R (Serach here for MySQL installer community)
2. Click on Reconfigure which is next to MySQL server

[image]

3. Click Next

[image]

4. Click Next

[image]

5. Add new password
   [image]

6. Click Next => Next => Execute
7. Its done